# Struct with variable length with Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, struct

I am collecting data from a process in a struct as follows;

```
timepace(1,i) = struct(...
    'stageNo',str2num(stageNo), ...
    'split1', splits(1,1),...
    'split2', splits(1,2),...
    'split3', splits(1,3) );
```

However, the number of “splits” is can vary from 2 to 10. At the moment I am using a longer code than shown above to allocate all the “splits” and if not, put a 0. But this makes me create a lot of unused data for the “just in case” situation of having so many splits.
Would there be a way to make the length of it flexible? I know the required final number because it is an input to the system for each query that I do.

Any ideas on how to make it flexible and related to a length variable?

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like

```
S = struct('stageNo',str2num(stageNo));

for jj = 1:size(splits,2)
    S.(['split' num2str(jj)]) = splits(1,jj);
end

timepace(1,i) = S;
```

It's called "dynamic field reference". You can find more information [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an array instead of `struct`:

```
timepace(1,i) = struct(...
    'stageNo',str2num(stageNo), ...
    'split',  *PUT HERE YOUR ARRAY*...
);
```

Don't forget that in the case of cell array, you need additional `{}` brackets.

```
timepace(1,i) = struct(...
    'stageNo',str2num(stageNo), ...
    'split',  {{1,2,3,4,5}}...
```

);

If you must use `struct` than see Rodys answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use cell2struct:

```
 labels = {'split1','split2','split3',...}
 c = num2cell(splits);
 f = labels(1:numel(c));
 s = cell2struct(c,f,2);
```